# C# using a variable as a pointer to a location in 2D array

Tags: c#, pointers, multidimensional-array, location

First of all I’m NOT a seasoned programmer and I’m learning C# on the fly for a project at work.

Without going into the overall details of the project, it basically is an analytic calculator for generating thermal vs time data for a semiconductor junction. The “user” inputs will be loaded from text file that contain names of a parameters along with values. Example “Rth_1 ,0.023”

Since I don’t have control of the actual placement of each parameter in the text file it is necessary to sort as I load all data into a 2D array as it is read from the text file and then keep track of where each parameter is in the 2D array.

So what I’m wanting to do is use a variable or pointer to certain location.
Something like “Param1 = [12],[2]”

Is this possible in C#?

Comment: You could use 2 variables of type int, one for x and the other for y.

Comment: I know of using 2 vars as [i][j], but really would like to have one that points to a cell in the 2d array

Comment: You can, but it doesn't sound like you need a 2D array at all... You want to define a custom object, for example: `class ThermalData { public string Name { get; set; } public float Value { get; set; } }`. Then you can have a simple 1D array of these objects.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can use several approaches for having "single" pointer to the cell in 2D array. The most straightforward is to use [Point class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point(v=vs.110).aspx). Well, Point is a position in a discrete space after all.

Another approach is to use bit shifting if you know that your array will not be more than 2^32 or 2^16. Then just use `i<<16+j` to store the pointer.

Or you can use `KeyValuePair<int, int>`. Or `Tuple<int, int>`.